# Can you relocate to Taiwan after being deported from China?

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, relocation, china, taiwan

My Ukranian girlfriend was recently deported from China for a minor offense. A training school arranging to take some kids on a tour to europe invited her to give basic Russian and Ukranian lessons to kid for a month to prep the kids before they go to Europe, unfortunately the cops came and asked for her work permit and the whole thing escalated real quick

She wants to relocate to Taiwan to be closer to me since I'm still in China. The problem is we're worried that might not be possible since China and Taiwan are sort of linked. We're worried she might not be granted access to enter Taiwan.

Can anyone advise whether she will be able to relocate to Taiwan or not?

Comment: Whether your girlfriend can move to the Republic of China (Taiwan) will depend on the Taiwanese authorities' assessment of her personal circumstances, her travel history, her legal history, the type of visa or entry she seeks, and the most important factor of all — their assessment of whether she'll leave afterwards. Not having followed the rules in China and having been deported won't help. Even knowing those things, no one here will be able to do more than guess if she'll succeed. I think this is unanswerable. Searching the web for "Moving to Taiwan" returns a lot of articles and opinions.

Comment: She went to China to work without a visa? She is very lucky she was only deported. That is not a minor offense. Maybe to you, but not to China. I think you should realistically plan for the majority of your time with her to be spent in her home country from now on.

Comment: @ouflak also not a huge issue just means you get banned from entering for a long period should you wish to, not like they will jail you for such thing unless it’s on mass scale